# trouble with make install when building gcc14

Tags: gcc, makefile

I'm getting an error when trying to build gcc 14 from source and not sure what to do about it

```
pwd
/home/m/Desktop/dev/gcc/gccbuild
ls ..
gccbuild gccgit gccout
```

gccgit is the place gcc was cloned to, then it was built to gccbuild, now I'm trying to install it to gccout

```
make DESTDIR=`realpath ../gccout` install
```

but I get this error:

```
g++ -std=c++11  -fno-PIE -c  -DIN_GCC_FRONTEND -g -O2     -DIN_GCC    -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wconditionally-supported -Woverloaded-virtual -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-overlength-strings -Werror -fno-common  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -fno-PIE -I. -Ic -I../../gccgit/gcc -I../../gccgit/gcc/c -I../../gccgit/gcc/../include  -I../../gccgit/gcc/../libcpp/include -I../../gccgit/gcc/../libcody  -I../../gccgit/gcc/../libdecnumber -I../../gccgit/gcc/../libdecnumber/bid -I../libdecnumber -I../../gccgit/gcc/../libbacktrace   -o c/c-typeck.o -MT c/c-typeck.o -MMD -MP -MF c/.deps/c-typeck.TPo ../../gccgit/gcc/c/c-typeck.cc
../../gccgit/gcc/c/c-typeck.cc: In function ‘int convert_arguments(location_t, vec<unsigned int>, tree, vec<tree_node*, va_gc>*, vec<tree_node*, va_gc>*, tree, tree)’:
```

[...] (truncated excess error output for readability; if necessary I'll post the rest)

```
../../gccgit/gcc/c/c-typeck.cc:12212:16: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
12212 |       error_at (location, invalid_op_diag);
      |       ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
```

I don't really understand where make gets its flags such as -Wformat-security or how to suppress or override this behavior.

Comment: You could try adding `CXXFLAGS=-Wno-error` to your `make` command.

Comment: I tried that by doing `make CXXFLAGS=-Wno-error DESTDIR=\`realpath ../gccout\` install`, and `CXXFLAGS=-Wno-error make DESTDIR=\`realpath ../gccout\` install`, and by going into the Makefile and adding it at line (for me, 364, and I *think* that's the right line but not 100% certain), but none of those worked, or even affected the error output. it looks like that flag is not making it to the g++ command that actually gets run